# Explanation of function from Gleez project

Tags: php, foreach, reference, kohana

Gleez project written in Kohana framework I am using it to learn.
I have some questions about how works the following code.
It is used to generate tree from given information and then recursive function is using this generated tree to create the structure.

I give a query result $tree to a function which contains 
parent id = pid
The loop runs through each item checking if pid is set (using isset) and if so then adds empty array $d['children'] to the current item. Reference is used to change item's value in foreach loop.

1. My question is why reference is used, because even if isset is false empty array $d['children'] is added? I guess i just don't understand the use of this function.
   2.why my simplifyed function without reference still does add $item['children'] where pid = Null

   ```
   private function generate_tree($tree)
   {
   $menu = array();
   $ref  = array();

   foreach($tree as $d)
   {
       $d['children'] = array();

       if(isset($ref[$d['plid']]))
       {
           // we have a reference on its parent
           $ref[ $d['plid'] ]['children'][ $d['mlid'] ] = $d;
           $ref[ $d['mlid'] ] =& $ref[ $d['plid'] ]['children'][ $d['mlid'] ];
       }
       else
       {
           // we don't have a reference on its parent => put it a root level
                       $menu[$d['mlid']] = $d;
           $ref[$d['mlid']] =& $menu[$d['mlid']]; // both pointing to the mlid
       }
   }

   return $menu;
   ```

   }

I simplifyed the function to just add $item['children']; to result $tree if parent id is set.
I give generate_tree function these parameters.

```
    array(4){
         [0]=> array(2) 
             { 
             ["id"]=> string(1) "2"
             ["pid"]=> NULL
             } 
         [1]=> array(2) 
             { 
             ["id"]=> string(1) "3" 
             ["pid"]=> NULL 
             }
         [2]=> array(2) 
             { 
             ["id"]=> string(1) "6"
             ["pid"]=> string(1) "2"
             } 
         [3]=> array(2) 
             { 
             ["id"]=> string(1) "8"
             ["pid"]=> string(1) "3"
             } 
    }


    private function generate_tree($menu) {

    $tree = array();


    foreach ($menu as $item) {

        $item['children'] = array();

        if (isset($tree[$item['pid']])){
            $tree[$item['pid']['children']] = $item;
        } 
        else{

            $tree[$item['pid']] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

the output of $tree. As you can see ["pid"]=> Null, but still $item['children'] was added.

```
    array(3) {
        [""]=> array(3) 
             {
             ["id"]=> string(1) "3"
             ["pid"]=> NULL
             ["children"]=> array(0) { }
             }
        [2]=> array(3) 
            {
            ["id"]=> string(1) "6"
            ["pid"]=> string(1) "2"
            ["children"]=> array(0) { }
            } 
        [3]=> array(3) 
        { 
        ["id"]=> string(1) "8" 
        ["pid"]=> string(1) "3" 
        ["children"]=> array(0) { } 
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried removing the reference and checking what happens if you do? Sometimes it's the best just to witness what happens :)

Comment: Yes, I did simplify the code, removed the reference, i

Comment: I'll  tray to correct my question, because it's my first question ever and I assume it's not the best one.

Comment: It's a valid question in my opinion, you are confused by the use of reference. The best way to check what happens is to remove it and see the result after that.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform operations by reference you are using same variable, anything you do to it will be parsed to any other referenced variable.

When you **do not** perform operations by reference you are creating a copy of the variable and anything you do to the copy **will not** be parsed to any other copied variables.

Then why is the code wrote this way? It's done like this so the programmer doesn't have to worry about updating the array all the way down the tree when a match is found.

Comment: When using reference.I think I didn't understand  "all the why down" could you point me to the right path.

Comment: You can think of an array as a Tree. A Tree can have many Branches and Branches can have many Branches. You can walk/traverse the Branches, meaning going down/through the array or up/out of the array. In this referenced example the programmer doesn't have to make any attempt to maintain the hierarchy because the children are the reference of the parent element and its children are referenced of its parent element. Using this model we can update any branch that is n elements deep by only needing to know its top level position. "All the way down" means that there are no additional levels left.

Comment: your explanation was great. But still don't understand my second question of simplifyed example without reference.

Comment: This is because PHP type juggles. Use is_null() instead. Provided is a [link](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) to show how PHP's is_null(), empty() and isset() functions work.